# Spark On Windows--rdd.count() doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I installed Spark on Windows primarily according to the instructions in the book "Frank Kane's Taming Big Data with Apache Spark and Python".  They seem to align with other instructions I've found online.  It involves installing java, python, scala, and spark, and setting the environmental variables and paths.  I am able to run java and python.  In order to run pyspark, I have to run pyspark.cmd I'm using the Canopy command prompt).  This does book up the spark.

I then run:
rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")

and then

rdd.count()

But I get this error:

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")
>>> rdd.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1073, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1064, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 935, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 834, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2073)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

What do I have wrong?

Comment: Add environment variable PYSPARK_PYTHON and set value to python. It will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your README file to hdfs or use full path to file with prefix "file://".